# Trying to dispatch an action by itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When the server throws 401 response, I am handling the error by requesting new authentication token after which I need to continue with the request that actually meant to happen. Therefore, I am not able to access the class method as scope i.e this is undefined within the response.

```
 ;(function(){
    var someAction  = {
    addItem: function (entity, data) {
               var that = this; /* this is undefined, out of scope  */
                return function (dispatch) {
                    dispatch(apiActions.apiRequest(entity));

                    return (ApiUtil.create(entity, data).then(function (response) {
                        dispatch(apiActions.apiResponse(entity));
                        browserHistory.goBack();
                    }, function (error) {
                        if (error.status == 401) {
                            ApiUtil.refreshSession().then(function (response) {
                                dispatch(that.addItem); /** unable to access that as i need to recall the same action after I get refresh token**/
                            });
                        } else {
                            dispatch(apiActions.apiResponse(entity));
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
    }
    })();         


    ;(function(){
    /* within react component i've invoked this method */
     this.props.actions.addItem('entity', some_entity);

     var mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
            return {
                actions: bindActionCreators(_.assign({}, crudActions, apiActions), dispatch)
            }
        };
     module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
    })();
```

Are there any other options regarding this scenario, I am very much willing to listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch the same action just by

```
dispatch(someAction.addItem)
```